# Single cycle MIPS processor instruction execution

Tags: mips, verilog

I am executing six instructions in this Single Cycle MIPS processor. 
I am unable to figure error in ALU module.
Six instructions i am trying to execute are: Add, Sub, AND, OR, Load, Store
Right now, i am getting correct result for Addition only.

In five bit MUX, i have given an input 'a' and 'b'. How can i relate this input 'a' and 'b' to instruction source and detonation registers.

Also, how can i add 4 byte after the execution of each instruction (i.e. my program counter is unable to increment).

```
   //ALU Block
    module ALU (FunctField,ReadData1,out_inALU, ALUOp,ctr1,result);
    input ALUOp;
    input [5:0]FunctField;
    input [31:0] ReadData1;
    input [31:0] out_inALU;
    output  [2:0] ctr1;
    reg [2:0] ctr1;
    output [31:0] result;
    reg  [31:0] result;
    always @(*)
    begin
    if(ALUOp == 1)      //Arithmetic' Type Instructions
    begin
  case(FunctField)        
  //begin
    6'b100000: ctr1 = 3'b010;    //ADDITION in 'R' Type
    6'b100010: ctr1 = 3'b110;    // SUBTRACTION in 'R' Type
    6'b100100: ctr1 = 3'b000;     // AND in 'R' Type
    6'b100101: ctr1 = 3'b001;    //  OR in 'R' Type
  endcase
end

if(ALUOp == 0)
begin     //   LW/SW Type Instructions
    if (ctr1 == 3'b010)
        result = ReadData1 + out_inALU ;
    else if (ctr1 == 3'b110)
        result = ReadData1 - out_inALU ;
    else if (ctr1 == 3'b000)
        result = ReadData1 & out_inALU ;
    else if (ctr1 == 3'b001)
        result = ReadData1 | out_inALU;
    end 
result = ReadData1 | out_inALU ;
end
endmodule


// Data memory
   module data_memory (ReadAddr, WriteAddr, WriteData1, clock, 
            MemWrite, MemRead,ReadData);

   input    [31:0] ReadAddr, WriteAddr, WriteData1;
   input    clock, MemWrite, MemRead;
   reg  [31:0] mem[0:50];       // For simulation this no. is enough
   reg  [31:0] i;           // Temporary variable
   output   [31:0] ReadData;
   reg  [31:0] ReadData;

   initial
   begin
   //   Initial read-out
   ReadData = 0;
   //   Initial memory content for testing purpose
   for ( i = 0; i <= 50; i = i+1)
        mem[i] = i;
   end

  //      Memory content is always fetched with positive edge clock
  always @(posedge clock)
  begin
  wait ( MemRead )
    #10 ReadData = mem[ReadAddr];
  wait ( MemWrite )
    #10 mem[WriteAddr] = WriteData1;
  end

  endmodule


 //   Instruction Memory
   module inst(addr,clock,instruction);
   input clock;
   input [ 31 : 0 ] addr;
   output [ 31 : 0 ] instruction;
   reg [ 31 : 0 ] instruction;
   reg [ 31 : 0 ] MEM[0 :31 ] ;
   initial
   begin
   MEM[ 0 ] <= 32'h10000011;
   MEM[ 1 ] <= 32'h10000011 ;
   MEM[ 2 ] <= 32'h20000022 ;
   MEM[ 3 ] <= 32'h30000033 ;
   MEM[ 4 ] <= 32'h40000044 ;
   MEM[ 5 ] <= 32'h50000055 ;
   MEM[ 6 ] <= 32'h60000066 ;
   MEM[ 7 ] <= 32'h70000077 ;
   MEM[ 8 ] <= 32'h80000088 ;
   MEM[ 9 ] <= 32'h90000099 ;
   end
   always @( posedge clock )
   begin
   instruction <= MEM[ addr ] ;
   end
   endmodule


    //Main module
      module(reset, clock, regwrite,regDst,ALUSrc,MemtoReg,MemWrite,MemRead, input_PC)    
     input  reset,clock;
     input  regWrite;
     input  regDst;
     input  ALUSrc;
     input  MemtoReg;
     input  MemWrite;
     input  MemRead;
     input  [31:0] input_PC;

     wire [4:0] ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteReg;
     wire [31:0] WriteData;

    // Instantiation of modules
    //Program Counter

    wire [31:0] addr;
    PC x1(input_PC,clock,reset,addr);

    // Instruction Memory
    wire [31:0] instruction; 
    inst x2(addr,clock,instruction);

    //Multiplexer with regDst
    reg[4:0] inputa,inputb;
    MUX_2to1_5bit x3(inputa,inputb,regDst,WriteReg);

    //Register File

    wire [31:0] ReadData1,ReadData2;
    Register_32 x4 ( ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteReg, WriteData, clock,
    RegWrite,ReadData1, ReadData2);


    //Sign Extender

    wire [31:0] out_sign;
    SignExtender_16to32 x5(immediate, out_sign);

     //Multilpexer ALUSrc
     wire [31:0] out_inALU;
    MUX_2to1 x6( ReadData2 , out_sign, ALUSrc,out_inALU );

    //ALU
    wire [31:0] result;
    wire [2:0] ctr1;
    ALU x7 (FunctField,ReadData1,out_inALU, ALUOp,ctr1,result);

    //Data Memory
    reg [31:0]  ReadAddr;
    reg [31:0]  WriteAddr;
    wire [31:0] ReadData;
    data_memory x8(ReadAddr, WriteAddr, WriteData, clock, MemWrite, 

    MemRead,ReadData);

    //Multiplexer MemtoReg
    MUX_2to1_memreg  x9( result,ReadData,MemtoReg,WriteData);
    endmodule

    // Mux2 to 1_32 bit


  module MUX_2to1( ReadData2 , outputData, ALUSrc,out_inALU );
  input [31:0] ReadData2,outputData;
  input ALUSrc;
  output [31:0]out_inALU;
  reg [31:0]out_inALU;

  always @(ReadData2  or outputData or ALUSrc )
    begin
      case(ALUSrc)

          1'b0:   out_inALU=ReadData2;
          1'b1:  out_inALU=outputData;

      endcase
    end
endmodule 

     // Mux 2 to 1 5 bit
    module MUX_2to1_5bit( inputa , inputb, regDst, WriteReg);
      input [4:0] inputa, inputb;
      input regDst;
      output [4:0]WriteReg;
      reg [4:0]WriteReg;

      always @(inputa or inputb or regDst )
        begin 
          case(regDst)

              1'b0:   WriteReg=inputa;
              1'b1:  WriteReg=inputb;

          endcase
        end
     endmodule 



// Mux 2 to 1 for memory register
  module MUX_2to1_memreg( result,ReadData,MemtoReg,WriteData);
  input [31:0] ReadData,result;
  input MemtoReg;
  output [31:0] WriteData;
  reg [31:0]WriteData;

  always @(* )
    begin
      case(MemtoReg)

          1'b0:   WriteData= result ;
          1'b1:  WriteData= ReadData;

      endcase
    end
endmodule 


// Progrma COunter
module PC(input_PC,clock,reset,addr);
input reset,clock;
input [31:0] input_PC;
output reg [31:0] addr;

always @(posedge clock)
begin
if (reset)
addr=0;
else 
addr=input_PC+4;
end
endmodule

//Register

module Register_32 ( ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteReg, 
            WriteData, clock, RegWrite,ReadData1, ReadData2);
input [4:0] ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteReg;
input [31:0] WriteData;
input   clock, RegWrite;
output  [31:0] ReadData1, ReadData2;
reg [31:0] ReadData1, ReadData2;

reg [31:0] mem[0:31];   // 32 32-bit registers
reg [5:0] i;        // Temporary variable

initial
begin
    //  Initial registers for testing purpose
    for ( i = 0; i <= 31; i = i+1)
        mem[i] = i;
    //  Initial start-up
    ReadData1 = 0;
    ReadData2 = 0;
end

//      Data from register is always fetched with positive edge clock
always @(posedge clock)
begin
    #1 ReadData1 = mem[ReadReg1];
    #1 ReadData2 = mem[ReadReg2];
    if ( RegWrite == 1)
        #1 mem[WriteReg] = WriteData;
end

endmodule


// Sign extender
module SignExtender_16to32(immediate,out_sign);
  input[15:0]  immediate;
  output[31:0] out_sign;
  reg [31:0] out_sign;

  always@(*)
    begin

      out_sign[15:0]  = immediate[15:0];
      out_sign[31:16] = {16{immediate[15]}};

    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You could increment the program counter as below but it will have wrap around issues. Better to have a signal to latch the input address or at reset do `add = input_PC;`

```
module PC(input_PC,clock,reset,addr);
input reset,clock;
input [31:0] input_PC;
output reg [31:0] addr;

always @(posedge clock)
begin
if (reset)
addr= 0;
else 
addr=input_PC+4+addr;
end 
endmodule
```

you would want the mem to ignore lower 2 bits in inst module else after reading mem 0 it will read mem[4] .

```
   instruction <= MEM[ addr[31:2] ] ;
```

You need to connect the instruction to the ALU module , cannot offer any suggestion as i cannot figure what your instruction decoding scheme is.